# QGIS 2.18.4 show '0' value disappear with labels with rules

Tags: qgis, expression

I need help to show '0' value with expression.  When I show only label from a row, '0' appear, but I want to add the expression in the color :

```
CASE
WHEN  "max_44_mol_pharma"  < 100 THEN  color_rgb( 0,0,0)
WHEN  "max_44_mol_pharma"  >=  100 THEN  color_rgb( 255,0,0)
END
```

[image] 
[image]
[image]
[image]
and the '0' disappear.  Can you help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Where the `0` value should be located? Is it under the column `max_44_mol_pharma` and you want to show it in a different color, or what?

Comment: Columns sorry ;-)  I have differents columns and want for each show the value.  If I use only labels to show the values, everything is ok i see the '0' for each columns.  But i would like to use the expression above to color the values in black and red with the limit of 100.  And with this expression, the '0' value is no longer visible !

Comment: I hope it is possible !

Comment: Perhaps it would help to use the color format rgba, which adds an opacity value. When the opacity is set to 0, the label will be invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this option ON in the `Labels` tab of the `Layer Properties`.

It does not seems to be ralated with the condition.

[image]

**Updated with your new screenshots**:

[image]

The filter is a logical expression, so it filters out when the expression in the field is `FLASE` or (which is the same in this context) zero.

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work with this option !

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong! Under Description, there is "filtre" and I juste select the field I wanted.  Maybe I have to do other thing ?

Comment: paste the screenshots of the conditional labels, is the zero in a different field than the other values?

Comment: Hello Marco, I send the details of my data

Comment: Do you want to filter out some records? It does not look like, but you are the one who knows what do you want to present, but there is your mistake

Comment: To say true, I have to do quick map with the differents values, so I search tutorials for that and found the solution with labels with rules.  But this is the first time I make a try with it ;-)  I found that, if I doesn't select a filtre, no value appears ! so I select the column I need.  And have the problem with '0'.    So I don't know how to correct !

Comment: Then just write 1 in the expression, so it is `TRUE` for all values